# Late 80s early 90s dimension travel flick

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, space

hope someone can help me identify this film.

I've seen it sometimes in the 90s and from what I remember it looked like an old eighties/early nineties production. There were at least two teenagers, a boy and a girl, that were traveling through different dimensions. At one point, they are in space, fighting a sort of alien creature, after which the space ship explodes and they travel to a sort of medieval arthurian land, where the king is being visited by a noble that they identify as the villain and I think the wizard tells them how to travel through time. Near the end, I remember that the girl is tempted to dimension warp again, but sees that the next dimension is a sort of dark city ruled by biker gangs, and they decide against it.

That's pretty much all I remember. It would be great if somebody could figure it out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds a bit like sliders

Comment: Not it. This one was a movie, not a series, and it had more of a teen humor, despite the dark atmosphere.

Comment: No no, I could have swore I saw a one shot Sliders movie. Or atleast I attributed it to sliders. You know how those Sci fi c movies of the week are.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be Waxwork II: Lost in Time?

In that movie, a teen boy & girl are traveling through different time periods, including one where they're onboard a spaceship, being attacked by an alien creature.  Then they travel to medieval times & face off versus an evil king/prince and his henchmen. But I don't recall any time period with biker gangs in the movie.